# Memory leak with lists c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The idea of the function is to divide the original list in X Lists all gather in a single array without delete nor creating new Cells.
The function do his job great but when I check the leaks with valgrind or Dr. Memory, It appears to have some leak problems...

```
List* function (List & todivide, int t = 2){
  Cell* aux = todivide.l;       // l is the head of the list
  int tam = (todivide.size()/t == 0) ? todivide.size()/t : todivide.size()/t+1;
  List* arrayoflists = new List [tam];

  for(int i = 0, k = 0; aux != 0; i++){
      if(i%t == 0){
          arrayoflists[k].l = aux;
          aux = aux->sig;
          k++;
      }
      if(i%t == t-1){
          Cell* p = aux->sig;
          aux->sig = 0;
          aux = p;
      }
  }
  l.l = 0;

  return arrayoflists;
}
```

I see nothing wrong... Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code. Therefore, the leak must be either in the code that's not shown, or in combination with the shown, and the not shown code. To avoid uselessly wasting time hunting down memory leaks, learn how to use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I know it is not related to main question but didn't you want to write `(todivide.size()%t == 0)`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong inside the function but since you're *returning* a pointer that you created using new, you might be forgetting to delete the returned pointer where ever you're using it outside the function.

Comment: You-re right, I tried to: "delete [] arrayoflist" after receive the array in the main and the leaks were fixed... I don't understand why I must do this indeed I have declared the destructor...

Comment: Hmm, might be something going wrong in the destructor then. Glad you could get it fixed though.